# Blackberry - Get list of files and folders on device and SD card

Tags: blackberry

I am writing an app for Blackberry and will need to scan the device for certain types of media, for example, pictures, MP3s etc.

Is there an easy way to scan all the files and folders on the device itself (even just the `home/user/` directory), as well as the SD card?

I'm assuming the solution is some sort of recursive algorithm whereby I get a list of directories in the current path, and scan through them, but how do I get the list of all folders (as well as files) in the path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this link](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cc986cf/n/fileexplorerdemo.zip)

And download zip file with FileExplorerDemo. Scroll the opened page down and click on "Slow download" button.

Otherwise you may check the JDE samples folder for this sample code.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look through that and it looks like it has what I need!

Comment: The source code is available in JDE samples as I mentioned before. And this code is a quite big application, not a snippet.